# Match path with or without url parameters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a simple regex to match the following:

```
/path/foo.html
/path/foo.html?a=b
/path/foo.html?a=b&b=c
```

but not /path/foo.htmlx or anything else which is not foo.html + url parameter.

I tried

```
/path/foo.html(?:\?|$)
```

but it does not seem to work in my java project.

Comment: What you have now and what do you want match?

Comment: Post your code so we can tweak it to make it work.

Comment: [Your regex: `/path/foo\.html(?:\?|$)` is working fine here](https://regex101.com/r/5QK0LN/1)

Comment: @anubhava although the regex is valid, could it be used wrong in the code. And for example `String.matches(String regex)` tells whether the String match the whole regex and therefore this regex would fail.

Comment: Yes it is possible that OP is using `matches` method

Comment: @NoobieNoob did you test it? `/path/foo\.html(?:\?|$)([a-zA-Z0-9\=\&]*)`

Answer (score 1):

[`String.matches(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) does a full match

> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form str.matches(regex) yields exactly the same result as the expression

So for example `"/path/foo.html?a=b".matches("/path/foo.html(?:\\?|$)")` returns false, because the String doesn't end after the `?`.

You can use `"/path/foo.html(\\?.*)?"`

Answer (score 1):

For URL part use regexp provided by @reconnect:

`^[^?]*`

match from start until `?` character meet.

for search exactly /path/foo.html use:

`^/path/foo.html`

if you need check that part of something exists with matches in the line add `^` - start of line and `$` end of line, and in this case you should care about characters between end of your conditions, basically replaced with `.*`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly understand what you trying to match, but if you want match only URL part without search string:

`/^[^?#]*/`

# - hash string, too can pass some arguments

Comment: If you don't understand what OP wants, ask in the comments, don't answer based on an assumption.

Comment: @Adelin may I decide this without you?

Comment: @Adelin if it's better for you - well